# expression must have pointer to function type

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm attempting to learn how to use pointers. I have the following file that creates coordinates and then moves them in random directions using a random number generator.

The value sigmaf_point is inputted from a text file:

```
 void methane_coords(double *&sigmaf_point)

 double dummy_int = 1;
 string dummystring;
        string s;

        ifstream Dfile;
        std::stringstream out;

        out << 1;
        s = out.str() + ".TXT";
        Dfile.open (s.c_str());

        if (Dfile.fail())
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<dummy_int; i++)
        {
        Dfile >> sigmaf_point[i];
        }
```

Which I then use in another function:

```
double initial_energy(double **coords_fluid, const double *box_size){


// Loop over all pairs of atoms and calculate the LJ energy
double total_energy = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= n_atoms-1; i++)
{   

        sf1=sigmaf_point(coords_fluid[i][3]);
        ef1=epsilonf_point(coords_fluid[i][3]);

        // Energy fluid-fluid
        for (int j = i+1; j <= n_atoms-1; j++)
        {               
            sf2=sigmaf_point(coords_fluid[j][3]);
            ef2=epsilonf_point(coords_fluid[j][3]);             

            double delta_x = coords_fluid[j][0] - coords_fluid[i][0];
            double delta_y = coords_fluid[j][1] - coords_fluid[i][1];
            double delta_z = coords_fluid[j][2] - coords_fluid[i][2];

            // Apply periodic boundaries
            delta_x = make_periodic(delta_x, box_size[0]);
            delta_y = make_periodic(delta_y, box_size[1]);
            delta_z = make_periodic(delta_z, box_size[2]);

            // Calculate the LJ potential
            s=(sf1+sf2)/2.0;
            e=pow((ef1*ef2),0.5);
            double r = pow((delta_x*delta_x) + (delta_y*delta_y) +
                      (delta_z*delta_z),0.5)/s;

        double e_lj = 4*((1/pow(r,12.0))-(1/pow(r,6.0))/e);

        total_energy = (total_energy + e_lj);
        }
    }
```

coords_fluid is created in the main file like so:

```
double **coords_fluid = new double*[5000];
```

Now the problem is with sf1=sigmaf_point(coords_fluid[i][3]);

I get the error "expression must have pointer to function type" for sigmaf_point. I'm a bit confused about this, I know it's about how I call the variable but can't seem to fix it.

Cheers

Comment: can you provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: when I google the error message I find a lot of information. What investigation have you done in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Rereference to pointers are completly useless since it a pointer is already a sort of reference.
So change `double *&` to `double *` or `double &`. It will be faster.

Besides I see that you're using `sigmaf_point` as a function and as an array.
Which one is it?
Could you give the declaration of `sigmaf_point`?

Assuming it's an array change

```
sf1 = sigmaf_point(coords_fluid[i][3]);
```

to

```
sf1 = sigmaf_point[coords_fluid[i][3]];
```